# expo-firebase-analytics screen resolutions aren’t send

Tags: google-analytics, expo, firebase-analytics

I’ve installed expo-firebase-analytics ( `expo-install expo-firebase-analytics` )

I’ve added and linked the google-service.json file from firebase console correctly and I can get datas on my google analytics dashboard.

However it seems that the screen resolution isn’t part of the sent datas …

In tech details > Screen resolutions that's what I have :

[image]

How can I get it ?